# I am not able to highlight a row in WPF data grid by comparing data in a column of the data grid to the same data sorted in an array

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a data grid with 6 columns and 20 rows. The data in one of the columns is an unsorted version of the same data in a descending ordered array. When a value in one of the columns matches one of the lowest 8 values in the sorted array I want the row containing the matched value to be highlighted. The code for comparing the two values works but I can't hook the result to something that will highlight the row.

I have tried binding the header name of the column to that property in code behind. With this approach the data grid displays data without an error but the row is not highlighted. This problem is beyond my expertise, and I would like some help.

Comment: "This problem is beyond my expertise" - is reading [stackoverflow guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and creating [mcve] within your expertise?

Comment: `DataGrid` has a `SelectedItem` property that you can bind to or set in code behind.  Have you tried that? Also this question is not organized well.  Try posting code so we can get a better idea of what you are trying. Your approach could be correct with a minor error and we would never know.